# Using *ngFor to pass object to component only passes first one

Tags: angular

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a loop like so:

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of employees">
  <div>{{data}}</div>
</tr>
```

It runs as you would expect and just prints all the objects in the collection.

However when I have

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of employees">
  <employee [employee]="data"></employee>
</tr>
```

However the first instance of employee does not have an object passed to it. All others are populated. This is my simple component that I'm rendering.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
})
export class Employee {
 @Input() employee: any;
}
```

What am I missing here?

This is the dom output:

```
    </tr>
    <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><tr>
      <div>data</div>
      <employee ng-reflect-employee="[object Object]" ng-version="5.2.10">
<td></td>


</employee>
    </tr><tr>
      <div>data</div>
      <employee ng-reflect-employee="[object Object]">
<td>[object Object]</td>
</employee>

    </tr><tr>
      <div>data</div>
      <employee ng-reflect-employee="[object Object]">
<td>[object Object]</td>
</employee>
```

Comment: how do you say undefined?

Comment: Only the first iteration of the loop passes the data to the component. None of the other iterations do.

Comment: how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Looking at the dom and trying to access the object.

Comment: I don't seem to see any issue with your code. Could you please post the output in the page of `data`? 
`<tr *ngFor="let data of employees">
  {{data}}
  <employee [employee]="data"></employee>
</tr>`

Comment: please add more details. your code looks perfect

Comment: Added dom output.

Comment: Could you please do a `console.log(this.employees)` inside your main component?

Comment: Could it simply be that the object at `employees[0]` isn't what you think it is?

Comment: I should look at the employees collection. employees[0] is likely to be empty

Comment: I mean I'm setting the collection myself. 

  `employees = [
    {
      name:'name',
      title:'name',
      profile:'profile'
    },
    {
      name:'name',
      title:'title',
      profile:'profile'
    },
    {
      name:'name',
      title:'title',
      profile:'profile'
    }]`

Comment: this is was is logged in console. 
`0
:
{name: "name", title: "name", profile: "profile"}
1
:
{name: "name", title: "title", profile: "profile"}
2
:
{name: "name", title: "title", profile: "profile"}
length
:
3`

Comment: Everything is fine when I don't have my custom component accepting the data. Once I start passing the object to my component, the first iteration just has undefined for data.

Comment: can you please put the relevant code on https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: @edkeveked https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4f91m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was coming from here:

```
 @NgModule({
  ...
  bootstrap: [EmployeeTable]
})
```

[Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsqjrk)

Your root component here is `EmployeeTable` and it should be the only one provided in the boostrap array.

Comment: Ok, great that worked. First time doing angular so thought all components had to go there.

Comment: No, not at all. Here is the official [doc](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping#the-bootstrap-array) about the component to declare in the boostrap array